# an issue regarding mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When executing the following MySQL query:

```sql
$sql = "SELECT username,wordpermin FROM user_records GROUP BY(username) ORDER BY wordpermin DESC LIMIT 20";
```

The problem am faced with is as follows:

I am making a table in for website where I want to show the users with the highest `word-per-min` count. However this count is way because am using `GROUP BY(username)`. It doesn't give me the highest value for that username, but instead it gives me the first value it sees.

What my expected result would be is: 20 users and in the order of words-per-minute, the words-per-second and for a total of 20 unique users. Unique because I don't want a user who has the first- and also the second highest word-per-min to be shown twice. Just show the highest record and put thisin the first spot.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This should start with a proper explanation of what your data model is here, and ideally include some sample data and show how exactly the output is wrong based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `MAX()` aggregate function for that column `wordpermin` and sort by that descending:

```
SELECT username, MAX(wordpermin) maxword 
FROM user_records 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY maxword DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way (if my implementation permitted).  Throw in a "SUM() or COUNT() depending on whichever is best for your purposes (I can't tell from your paragraph).

```
$sql = 
"
select username
from (
      SELECT   username
             , sum(wordpermin) as wordpermin
      FROM user_records 
      GROUP BY(username) 
      ORDER BY wordpermin DESC LIMIT 20
      )
order by wordpermin desc desc limit 20
"
```

Comment: this didn't work it shows nothing!! let me explain more and excuse my bad english, am trying to create a table in my website that shows the highest 'wordpermin' per unique user so if a user has the first and second highest 'wordpermin' i only want him to be the first not the second also i hope i made it clear? meaning only show a user once with his/her highest 'wordpermin' and i want the table to only have 20 user.

Comment: Okay, that helps a little.  Does your version of SQL have “MAX()” or “PARTITION” ? So you are going to want to partition if possible, and then within your partition on username use a max() function to find the max for each user.  Following this, use the “GROUP BY” nest like I did above to “LIMIT 20.”